# Loop through JSON data and appendChild <TR> is putting data in one row?

Tags: javascript, for-loop, html-table, appendchild

**Background:** I thought that I was going to end up with a dynamically created table that had the same number of `<TR>` tags as entries in the JSON data.

**Result:** The loop is only creating one table TR and putting all the data in one row.

Below is a snippet of the loop and table creation.

```
var tbl = document.createElement("table");
  var tblBody = document.createElement("tbody");
  var row = document.createElement("tr");
    var tdname = document.createElement('td');
    var tddate = document.createElement('td');
    var tdassigned = document.createElement('td');


    for (var i in data) {

    console.log("Hello world!" + i);
    tdname.appendChild(document.createTextNode(data[i].name));
    tddate.appendChild(document.createTextNode(data[i].date));
    tdassigned.appendChild(document.createTextNode(data[i].assigned));
    row.appendChild(tdname);
    row.appendChild(tddate);
    row.appendChild(tdassigned);


    }
    tblBody.appendChild(row);

    tbl.appendChild(tblBody);
    document.getElementById("tasklist").appendChild(tbl);
```

**Question:** Do I need to create a unique row variable for each loop?

Comment: Are you willing to use jquery?

Comment: I was hoping to keep it all vanilla if possible. This is more of a learning/training exercise so I guess there is no wrong answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were a couple of issues:

1. You're appending the text to the `td`, without clearing them. You can instead do `document.createElement('td')` within the loop for each of your data points.
2. You need a row for each iteration of data, this can also be done within the loop.
3. Please use [`let`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let) and [`const`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const) in place of [`var`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var). Please see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/762011/whats-the-difference-between-using-let-and-var) for more information.

Try something like this:

```js
const data = [{
    name: 'name1',
    date: 'date1',
    assigned: 'assigned1'
  },
  {
    name: 'name2',
    date: 'date2',
    assigned: 'assigned2'
  },
  {
    name: 'name3',
    date: 'date3',
    assigned: 'assigned3'
  },
];

let tbl = document.createElement("table");
let tblBody = document.createElement("tbody");
data.forEach(d => {
  let row = document.createElement("tr");
  row.appendChild(document.createTextNode(d.name));
  row.appendChild(document.createTextNode(d.date));
  row.appendChild(document.createTextNode(d.assigned));
  tblBody.appendChild(row);
});

tbl.appendChild(tblBody);
document.getElementById("tasklist").appendChild(tbl);
```

```html
<div id='tasklist'></div>
```

Hope this helps,

Comment: So creating the row variable each loop increment is what I was missing? I appreciate the help i will test now. Thanks! If anyone has feedback on my mistake that is always welcome too.

Comment: Yup, I've updated my answer to be a little more specific :)

Comment: Great thanks for the feedback and that solution works perfect. Again I appreciate the background on "Why" Checked.

Comment: No problem, glhf

Answer (score 0):

1. If `data` is an array of objects, start with an array method like `.map()` or `.forEach()` (demo uses `.foreach()` since a new array isn't really needed to make a table).
2. That will iterate through the array using `.insertRow()` for each object. Now convert each object into an element of it's values with `Object.values()` or `Object.keys()` (demo uses `Object.values()` which saves a step).
3. Now iterate through the array of values with `.forEach()` or `.map()` and `.insertCell()` then `.textContent` the values to the cells.

```js
let data = [{
    name: 'John Doe',
    date: '1/1/19',
    assigned: 'A'
  },
  {
    name: 'Jane Doe',
    date: '2/1/819',
    assigned: 'B'
  },
  {
    name: 'Darth Vader',
    date: '3/11/19',
    assigned: 'C'
  },
  {
    name: 'Obi Wan',
    date: '4/20/19',
    assigned: 'D'
  }
];

const frag = document.createDocumentFragment();
const tbl = document.createElement("table");
const tblB = document.createElement("tbody");
tbl.appendChild(tblB);
frag.appendChild(tbl);

data.forEach((obj, idx) => {
  let row = tblB.insertRow();
  Object.values(obj).forEach(val => {
    let cell = row.insertCell();
    cell.textContent = val;
  });
});

document.body.appendChild(frag);
```

Answer (score -1):

I just saw your comment that you prefer vanilla js. Here's the jquery way if interested.

```
var data = [
    { Column1: "col1row1", Column2: "col2row1" },
    { Column1: "col1row2", Column2: "col2row2" }
];

$("#tasklist")
    .append($('<table>')
        .append($('<tbody>')));

var tbody = $("#tasklist > table > tbody");

$.each(data, function (idx, item) {
    $(tbody).append($('<tr>')
        .append($('<td>')
            .text(item.Column1)
        )
        .append($('<td>')
            .text(item.Column2)
        )
    );
});
```